# Powershell Overriding Assignment and Comparison operators

Tags: powershell, class, operator-overloading, powershell-5.0

With Powershell 5 you can now implement custom classes.  With this eventually comes a time when you want to start overloading the operators to do things like

```
class Number
{
    [int] $value = 0

    Number() {} # empty constructor

    Number ([int]$somethingElse)
        {$this.value = $somethingElse}
}

$one = [number]::new(1)
$two = [number]::new(2)
$three = $one + $two
if ($three -eq ($one + $two))
    {"3 = 1 + 2"}
else
    {"3 <> 1 + 2 "}
```

But this doesn't seem to be well documented and after searching on Stack Overflow I can't find how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's commonly believed you can't do this in powershell.  And unfortunately after several google searches and searching on Stack Overflow I was about to give up.  But then I discovered [this post](https://gist.github.com/JFFail/c629e8a667bed62f3eb980e902491841) on gist and it turns out you can!

Given how hard it was for me to discover, I wanted to provide a clear and well formatted example for others (and my future self when I promptly forget how to do this)

Thanks to JFFail for posting [this](https://gist.github.com/JFFail/c629e8a667bed62f3eb980e902491841) to Github

You will need to overload these as appropriate, they should be self explanatory but feel free to ask if something isn't

```
SetValue([int]$newValue)
GetValue()
[boolean] Equals($otherNumber)
[string] ToString() # you can get more advanced by overloading "IConvertible.ToType" but that's a whole can of worms all it's own
static [MyClass] op_Addition   ([MyClass]$first, [MyClass]$second)
static [MyClass] op_Subtraction([MyClass]$first, [MyClass]$second)
static [MyClass] op_Multiply   ([MyClass]$first, [MyClass]$second)
static [MyClass] op_Division   ([MyClass]$first, [MyClass]$second)
```

For `-gt` and `-lt` you need to use the following.  Note while this does support `-eq`, you can get that by itself using `Equals(object)` as seen above, and that doesn't require the inheritance from `IComparable`

```
class MyClass : System.IComparable 
# requires inheritance from System.IComparable

[int] CompareTo($otherNumber)
# CANNOT declare type in parameter declaration, you'd have to check it later.
# 1 is greater than
# 0 is equal
# -1 is less than
# $null can be returned to indicate invalid comparison
```

Here's a working example

```
# If you don't need -lt or -gt then you don't have to inherit from System.IComparable
class Number : System.IComparable
{
    [int] $value = 0

    Number() {} # empty constructor

    Number ([int]$somethingElse)
        {$this.value = $somethingElse}

    [void] SetValue ([int]$newValue)
        {$this.value = $newValue}

    [int] GetValue()
        {return $this.value}

    [boolean] Equals($otherNumber)
    {
        if ($this.value -eq $otherNumber.GetValue())
            {return $true}
        else
            {return $false}
    }

    [int] CompareTo($otherNumber)
    {
        if ($this.value -gt $otherNumber.GetValue()) {return 1}
        if ($this.value -eq $otherNumber.GetValue()) {return 0}
        if ($this.value -lt $otherNumber.GetValue()) {return -1}
        return $null
    }

    [string] ToString()
        {return $this.value.ToString()}

    static [Number] op_Addition ([Number]$first, [Number]$second)
        {return [Number]::new($first.GetValue() + $second.GetValue())}

    static [Number] op_Subtraction([Number]$first, [Number]$second)
        {return [Number]::new($first.GetValue() - $second.GetValue())}

    static [Number] op_Multiply([Number]$first, [Number]$second)
        {return [Number]::new($first.GetValue() * $second.GetValue())}

    static [Number] op_Division([Number]$first, [Number]$second)
        {return [Number]::new($first.GetValue() / $second.GetValue())}
}

# Very Basic Unit Tests
$firstNumber = [Number]::new(8)
$secondNumber = [Number]::new(12)
$thirdNumber = [Number]::new(8)

if ($firstNumber -eq $secondNumber)
    {Write-Output ("{0} == {1}" -F $firstNumber, $secondNumber)}
else
    {Write-Output ("{0} <> {1}" -F $firstNumber, $secondNumber)}

if ($firstNumber -eq $thirdNumber)
    {Write-Output ("{0} == {1}" -F $firstNumber, $thirdNumber)}
else
    {Write-Output ("{0} <> {1}" -F $firstNumber, $thirdNumber)}

switch ($true)
{
    ($firstNumber -gt $secondNumber) {Write-Output ("{0} > {1}" -F $firstNumber, $secondNumber)}
    ($firstNumber -eq $secondNumber) {Write-Output ("{0} == {1}" -F $firstNumber, $secondNumber)}
    ($firstNumber -lt $secondNumber) {Write-Output ("{0} < {1}" -F $firstNumber, $secondNumber)}
}

$fourthNumber = $firstNumber + $secondNumber
Write-Output ("{0} = {1} + {2}" -F $fourthNumber, $firstNumber, $secondNumber)

$fifthNumber = $secondNumber - $thirdNumber
Write-Output ("{0} = {1} - {2}" -F $fifthNumber, $secondNumber, $thirdNumber)

$sixthNumber = $firstNumber * $secondNumber
Write-Output ("{0} = {1} * {2}" -F $sixthNumber, $firstNumber, $secondNumber)

$seventhNumber = $sixthNumber / $firstNumber
Write-Output ("{0} = {1} / {2}" -F $seventhNumber, $sixthNumber, $firstNumber)
```

And here's the output

```
> 8 <> 12
> 8 == 8
> 8 < 12
> 20 = 8 + 12
> 4 = 12 - 8
> 96 = 8 * 12
> 12 = 96 / 8
```